# Do 'memory boost' do really do something or is it a figment of imagination or something?

Tags: ram

I have no clue whether they work or not. Most apps. give or have something called 'memory boost' but there is no indication to know whether that really solves the issue or not. The issue is at times, especially in games, sometimes the app. hangs. Now by itself, it could mean many things, including memory leakage. Now while I can't figure out if it's memory leakage or whatnot on the mobile, the next best thing seems to be the above. But even after using any of the apps, the above continues to happen i.e. temporary hanging of apps. The mobile is new and everything. And this is on Android 12 on a Samsung Galaxy [phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m52_5g-11110.php)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand a word of what you have written. What is your question?

Comment: No. Memory booster apps can't do anything real. Memory management is a low level thing. Apps don't have access to such core features of operating system.

Comment: @Robert  irfan got it but you didn't. Basically, there are tonnes of apps. that claim to optimize the memory, just type 'memory booster' in Google Play Store and you will know what I mean. Apparently, they are all faking.

Comment: Whenever some cleanup app claims to have a memory booster, I'd skip that app entirely. All they do is "clean up memory" by killing processes to "free up memory" – which in most cases is rather counter-productive (as either those processes immediately restart, or the corresponding app just would need longer to startup affterwards and also use more resources like battery in the process). Task killers were a thing with early Android versions (before 4.x), and might be useful today in special cases where an app runs havoc – but else the OS manages memory pretty well nowadays.